# Referencing multiple pre-defined swagger 2.0 parameter definitions throwing error

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, apigee127

I've got two re-usable parameters defined in my swagger 2.0 file:

```
parameters:
  cursorParam:
    name: cursor
    in: query
    description: Pagination cursor.
    required: false
    type: string       
  limitParam:
    name: limit
    in: query
    description: Result limiter.
    required: false
    type: integer
```

And then in my route definitions (a GET in this case) I'm trying to reference both like this:

```
parameters:
    - $ref: '#/parameters/cursorParam'
    - $ref: '#/parameters/limitParam'
```

If I use one $ref, it seems to work OK (no compile errors), but if I try using both, it gawks at me:

```
Operation parameter already defined: undefined
at paths ▹ /users ▹ get ▹ parameters ▹ 1 ▹ name

Operation parameter already defined: undefined
at paths ▹ /authorisations ▹ get ▹ parameters ▹ 1 ▹ name
```

Moreover, if I pass these parameters in the query string and output `req.swagger.params`, I get an empty object. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a full SSCCE of the spec, generating the same error:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Test
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
x-a127-config: {}
x-volos-resources: {}
paths:
  /authorisations:
    x-swagger-router-controller: authorizations
    x-volos-authorizations: {}
    x-volos-apply: {}
    get:
      description: Returns all authorizations. Requires administrator rights to view unfiltered results, or if authenticated, returns the authorization entity belonging to the OAuth token.
      operationId: authorizationsGetAll #controller method name
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/cursorParam'
        - $ref: '#/parameters/limitParam'
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK

# reusable parameters have parameter definitions
parameters:
  cursorParam:
    name: cursor
    in: query
    description: Pagination cursor passed to a BaaS collection. Note that if this parameter is present, lastAccessedTimestamp.{channelType} should not be updated.
    required: false
    type: string       
  limitParam:
    name: limit
    in: query
    description: Result limiter to be passed to a BaaS collection.
    required: false
    type: integer
```

Comment: Any chance you can paste a full spec for easier testing?

Comment: Yeah, added. It's a bit of a beast, but I trimmed it down as much as I could to reproduce the errors.

Comment: Aha, you didn't mention in the question that you're talking about the apigee127 tool and I had assumed the error is from the swagger-editor. I'll try to get someone from the apigee team to look at it.

Comment: Yeah.... ooops ;) Looks like Jeremy's got a point, I'll update.

Comment: Jeremy is the best. You should always listen to him.

Comment: Careful, don't tell him that, it'll go to his head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using an old version of a127. The lack of reference support in all parts of the Swagger document were fixed recently so updating should fix this.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Silly question after all then. Haha and #protip: `apigee127` != `apigee-127` when using NPM so I discovered this morning.

Comment: Glad to help, sorry it too so long to respond and thanks webron for getting me involved.

Comment: No worries! Oddly I did `npm -g update apigee127` and I'm still not showing the correct version. Am I missing something?

Comment: `npm -g install apigee-127`